# Basic javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I’m trying to teach myself basic html with JavaScript using the Jquery library. With the code below I'm trying to change the p tags within the div red and the other p tags outside of the div yellow. The code below changes all the p tags yellow but when I place 4. above 3. it works. Just need a simple explanation why and also this is the html code http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/29/k9do.jpg/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testbutton").click(function() {
        $("div  p").css("background-color" , "red");
        $("p").css("background-color" , "yellow");
    });
});
```

Comment: you have to post your html also for us to be able to help

Comment: Advice. Use http://jsfiddle.net/ for such code or similar service)

Comment: All the p tags inside of the divs will be changed to red. Then all the p tags will be changed to yellow. If you change them to yellow first it will work because it will then only change the ones inside of the divs to red and not all of them like with the yellow one.

Comment: @user1014022 - If you want to include html in a question please copy and paste the actual text of the html, don't include a screenshot of the code loaded in an editor. (Though for this question the actual html is irrelevant, it is clear from the jQuery code alone what's happening, as explained by answers below.)

Answer (score 2):

Let me explain this

```
$("div p").css("background-color" , "red");
```

The above code will set the `background-color` red for all the p tags inside the div tag.

Now,

```
$("p").css("background-color" , "yellow");
```

The above code will set the `background-color` yellow for all the p tags, inside and outside the `div` tag too.

Now, when you do the reverse process, doing

```
$("p").css("background-color" , "yellow");
```

sets the `background-color` yellow for all the p tags, inside and outside the `div` tag first.

Next, doing this

```
$("div p").css("background-color" , "red");
```

sets the `background-color` red for all the p tags inside the div tag, but not the p tags outside the div. Hence this one works but not the first way.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is: **Each JavaScript statement is executed in the sequence/order they are written**.

So, in your case, the first statement will change the background color of **all p tags within a div** to red first. But the second statement will change the background color of **all** p tags to yellow. So, the second statement overwrites the previous changes, made by the first statement.

And that also explains, why, when you change those lines, it works as expected. Because in that case, the first statement will change the background color for **all** p tags to yellow. And, afterwards, the second statement will change the background color only **for those p tags within a div** tag to red.

**Update:** You can, alternatively, use something like this:

```
$('p').each(function(){
    var clr = ('DIV' === $(this).parent()[0].nodeName) ? 'red' : 'yellow';
    $(this).css('background-color', clr);
});
```

This code loops over all p tags, and set the background color based on the tag name of its parent element. If it's a div, it will use red, otherwise yellow. Here's a demo: [jsfiddle.net/3dL7r](http://fiddle.jshell.net/3dL7r/2/show/)

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about this problem the wrong way. If those style directions were all in a CSS file, the `div p` direction would trump the `p` direction, so the inner `<p>` would be red and the outer `<p>` would be yellow.

However, that's not what we're doing here. jQuery runs after the CSS has loaded initially, and doesn't care (or need to care) about page-wide CSS style rules; ALL styling changes that we make with jQuery will override the pre-set styles.

Let's look at what you wrote. Your first command,

`$("div p").css("background-color" , "#FF0000");`

translates into English as "Take all `<p>` tags that exist inside `<div>` tags and set their background color to red". Your second command,

`$("p").css("background-color" , "yellow");`

takes *all* `<p>` tags (including the ones we just turned red) and turns them yellow.

Answer (score 0):

4 (`"div  p"`) is more generic than 3 (`"div  p"`), so if you put 4 after 3 you will first color every p nested in a div in red, but immediatly  after you'll color it in yellow, since that is what you're saying in 4

Answer (score 0):

jQuerys `css()` functions sets the `style` attribute. Thus order mattes as both calls will set that attribute on some element and override each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div p").css("background-color" , "red");
```

The above line of code changes p (found) nested under div. Its the syntax of css.

```
$("p").css("background-color" , "yellow");
```

The above line of code changes all p tags found in DOM of HTML

Answer (score 0):

The `$("div p")` on line 3 targets all p tags inside a div (that's the cascading selector - the second tag must be inside the first) while the `$("p")` on line 4 targets *all* paragraph tags. The best way to have the different colours is indeed to move 4 above 3 - 3 is more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is more about css specificity. In line 3, your selector `div p` is setting all `p` that are within a `div` to red. In line 4 you are overriding this by setting **all** `p` to yellow (whether or not they are in a `div`).

Answer (score 0):

You need to first define outside `p tags` element with background , if you define it after  `p tags` inside `div` it will replace that div with yellow color.

```
$("#testbutton").click(function() {
     $("p").css("background-color" , "yellow");
     $("div p").css("background-color" , "#FF0000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In English,

First your colouring the `<p>` tags inside the `<div>` tags red.
Secondly your colouring all the `<p>` tags yellow. so of course there all going to be yellow.
You have to remember that styles in *JavaScript* don't act like *CSS* in relevance to priority. 
*JavaScript* adds the *CSS* style to inline `style=""` attribute so the only thing that will over-ride the style's is an `!important` witch you should **not** use.

so the reason it works when you put 4 above 3 is because the you are colouring all the `<p>` tags yellow, then specifically colouring the ones in the `<div>` tag red.

so basically any styles that are added to the element last in *JavaScript* will override the previous unless `!important` is used